# Using required attribute at class level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a class which is as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Firstname {get; set;}
  public string Surname {get; set;}
  public string Telephone {get; set;}
 //and around 10/15 more properties
}
```

I want to make all the properties required for the end user which I know I can use `[Required]` attribute to achieve. However I was wondering if there is a way where if I apply the `[Required]` attribute at a class level then all of the properties will automatically be required.  I know I can't use the built in `[Required]` attribute so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'd think no, even if you (could?) added `Required` attributes dynamically via a class attribute using reflection, I doubt your consumer would pick it up. `ctrl-c -> ctrl-v` is your friend here.

Comment: Yep. This is not possible. Just add the attribute to each property. Besides, doing that is far more explicit and therefore makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Check out  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760080/mvc-model-require-all-fields#answer-49810934)