# MVC model require all fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC application with EF6.  Is there a way to automatically set all properties of a model to `[Required]`?  Some of our models are large with all required fields.  Any way to save lines of code or make this cleaner?

```
public class Employee{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address 1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address 2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SSN { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double PayRate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PayType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool FullTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No. But it's needed only for `string` and nullable type properties.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098291/using-required-attribute-at-class-level this isn't possible. Also the commenter explains why you *shouldn't*, even if you could.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  That makes sense and answers my question.

Comment: If you want to make that the answer I'll approve it.

Comment: You can do it by modifying the model1.tt to adapt with your needs. But as mentioned by Adosi, you should do this only if it's absolutly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `MakeStringColumnsRequired` or `MakeAllNullableColumnsRequired` by means of Fluent API and "dynamic" `Expression`s:

```
protected void MakeStringColumnsRequired<T>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
    {
        var argParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var nameProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, prop.Name);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(nameProperty, argParam);
        modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(lambda).IsRequired();
    }            
}

protected  void MakeAllNullableColumnsRequired<T>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties()
        .Where(x => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(x.PropertyType) != null || x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        )
    {
        var argParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var nameProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, prop.Name);

        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>);
        funcType = funcType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T), prop.PropertyType);

        var lambdaMethod = typeof(Expression).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Lambda" && x.IsGenericMethod).First();
        lambdaMethod = lambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(funcType);                

        var lambda = lambdaMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { nameProperty, new ParameterExpression[] { argParam } });                

        var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();
        var entityPropertyMethods = entity.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Property" && !x.IsGenericMethod).ToList();                

        var entityPropertyMethod = entityPropertyMethods
            .Where(x => x.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().First().GetGenericArguments().Last() == prop.PropertyType)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if(entityPropertyMethod == null)
        {
            entityPropertyMethod = entity.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Property" && x.IsGenericMethod).Last();
            entityPropertyMethod = entityPropertyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType));
        }                

        var property = entityPropertyMethod.Invoke(entity, new object[] { lambda });
        var isRequired = property.GetType().GetMethod("IsRequired");
        isRequired.Invoke(property, null);                
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
#if StringColumnsRequired
    MakeStringColumnsRequired<Employee>(modelBuilder);
#else
    MakeAllNullableColumnsRequired<Employee>(modelBuilder)  
#endif
}
```

Comment: Would be good to show the OP how to to add nullable property support too

Comment: @Oliver, I posted code for all nullable types together with strings.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't implement this yet.  Next time it comes up I still may.  But it looks to be exactly what I'm looking for.